# Android: can not import org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader

Tags: android, encoding, parsing

I need to parse an UTF-8 encoded input stream, so I think the most appropriate method is to use

```
    XMLReader reader = new ExpatReader();
    InputSource source = new InputSource(in);
    source.setEncoding(encoding.expatName);
    reader.parse(source);
```

For that I need to import `org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader` but I cannot figure out how, I mean which Java package must I install from http://harmony.apache.org/download.cgi?

Or is there an alternative method to accomplish the same goal?

Thank you for helping.

Comment: are you looking to parse the xml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't instantiate an expat reader directly. just use the XMLReaderFactory.